# Overcoming TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

Tags: python, list, integer, typeerror

This is only part of my code. I am trying to run this code to generate a function, but am receiving the following error when running line 3 of depicted code: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

```
for j in range(1,100):
    c[j]=j/100
    s[j]= T - [8.314*[[j/100]*[np.log(j/100)]]]
```

Assume T has been initialized before these three lines. s and c are not initialized outside of the for loop. Is there anyway that I can get this function to be generated properly as numeric values?

Comment: What is `T`? What are you expecting this to do?

Comment: T is a number (ie. you can just put a 1 in it's place for sake of the problem, in my code I just have a number there). Eventually I am trying to plot s vs c.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to multiply a list by a list, which is causing the TypeError.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

# Dunno what T is

c = [0] * 100
s = [0] * 100

for j in range(1, 100):
    c[j] = j / 100
    s[j] = T - 8.314 * (j / 100) * np.log(j / 100)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Do you understand on a technical level why c and s have to be initialized before the for loop to be taken as numeric values? Prior to this, when I had not initialized c and prior, I had gotten an error indicating I couldn't multiply an integer by a float.